# What is omega, rho, and k in this complex numbers problem?

Tags: complex-numbers

A friend of mine was tasked with solving a complex equation $$z^3-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i=0$$ and asked me for help. When we both arrived at the same answer $$z=\sqrt[3]{\frac{1-\sqrt{3}i}{2}}$$, where the problem was "to solve for z", he thought the problem could not possibly end there; when he found an example problem, [shown here,](https://i.stack.imgur.com/28at1.png) neither of us knew what $\omega$ or $\rho$ was for, or how $k_0, k_1$, etc. was found. What is going on here, and how can I apply it to the real problem?

Comment: Is the first equation not missing "=0" ?

Comment: There are three different numbers which cube of to one.

Comment: Have you heard about [Roots of Unity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_of_unity) ?

Comment: The bottom section, listing $\omega_{0}, \omega_{1}, \omega_{2}$ describes the third roots of unity. In addition, the graph depicts the complex plane and the locations on said plane at which you could find these roots.

Comment: "neither of us knew what ω or ρ was for"  Um.. the pictures spells that out $\omega=-\frac 12 +\frac{\sqrt 3}2 i$. and $\rho = \sqrt{(-\frac 12)^2+(\frac{\sqrt 3}2)^2} =1$ and and $\theta = \frac {2\pi}3$.

Comment: A side comment: It is improper to write “$z=\sqrt[3]{\frac 12 - \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}i}$“ because radicals are not defined with complex arguments.  The equation should be left written as $z^3=\frac 12 - \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}i$ where you then find the three values for $z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\omega$ denotes one of the non-real cubic roots of unity $\;\omega=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{2i\pi}3}$. The others are $\omega^2=\bar\omega=\mathrm e^{\tfrac{4i\pi}3}=\mathrm e^{-\tfrac{2i\pi}3}$   and $1=\omega^0=\omega^3$.

As to $\rho$, it is the modulus of $\omega$ ($1$).

The three $k$s come from the way to determine the cubic roots  of a complex number:

If $z^3=\omega$, write complex numbers in exponential form: $z=r\mathrm e^{i\theta}$. If  $z^3=r^3\mathrm e^{3i\theta}=\omega$, we have
\begin{cases}
r^3=\rho=1 \iff r=1\\ 3\theta\equiv\frac{2\pi}3\mod 2\pi\iff \theta\equiv\frac{2\pi}9 \mod \frac{2\pi}3,
\end{cases}
in other words, as the argument of a complex number is defined modulo $2\pi$,
$$\theta=\frac{2\pi}9 + \frac{2k\pi}3,\quad(k=0,1,2).$$

Answer (score 0):

The question is: How do we solve $z^3 - \omega=0$.

The niave answer is $z =\sqrt[3]\omega$  but that's useless as we have no idea how to find *that*.  Also, as $z^3 - \omega = 0$ is third degree polynomial it will have three roots (or a multiple root).

....

Here is an aside:  What is $\sqrt[3] 1$?  You might say "well, it's $1$ because $1^3 =1$. But what if I asked you, what are the *other* two cube roots?  If $z^3 - 1= 0$ then $r_1= 1$ is one root, but what are the other two?  Well, $z^3 -1 = (z-1)(z^2 + z + 1)$ so if $z =1$ is one of the roots, then the other two roots will be the solutions to $z^2 + z + 1 = 0$ so by the quadratic formula they are $r_2= \frac {-1 +\sqrt{1-4}}2=-\frac 12 + \frac{\sqrt{-3}}2= -\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 3}2i$ and $r_3=\frac {-1-\sqrt{1-4}}2 = -\frac 12 -\frac {\sqrt 3}2i$.

So those are the three cube roots of $1$.  $r_1 = 1,r_2 = -\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 3}2i$ and $r_3 =-\frac 12 -\frac {\sqrt 3}2i$

Now note if $\omega_0$ is *one* solutions to $z^3 = \omega$ then $[(r_i)\omega_0]^3 = r_i^3\omega_1^3 = 1\cdot \omega$.  So the three solutions to $z^3 - \omega=0$ are $\omega_0, \omega_1= ( -\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 3}2i)\omega_0$ and $\omega_2 = ( -\frac 12 - \frac {\sqrt 3}2i)\omega_0$.

...

Now this image assumes you are familiar with polar coordinates.  I assume you are not.

So another aside.

.......

Crash course:

If $z = a+bi \ne 0$ than $|z| =\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$.  Let $r_z = |z| =\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$

$z = r_z(\frac a{r_z} + \frac b{r_z} i)$.  Let $c_z = \frac a{r_z}$ and $s_z = \frac b{r_z}$.

Then $z = r_z (c_z + s_z i)$ and $c_z^2 + s_z^2 =\frac {a^2}{r_z^2} + \frac {b^2}{r_z^2} = \frac {a^2}{a^2 + b^2} + \frac {b^2}{a^2 + b^2} = \frac {a^2 + b^2}{a^2+b^2} =1$.

Now if $c_z^2 + s_z^2 = 1$ then $c_z, c_z$ are on a unit circle and there is a unique $\theta_z; 0\le \theta_z < 2\pi$ where $c_z = \cos \theta_z$ and $s_z = \sin \theta_z$. So that means:

$z = r_z (\cos \theta_z + i\sin \theta_z)$ where $r_z= |z|$ then "size" of $z$, how far away from the origin that point $a+bi$ would be, and where $\theta_z$ represents the angle that the point $a+bi$ would have if we graphed it on a two dimensional plane.

So every $z=a+bi\ne 0$ can be written as $r(\cos\theta + i\sin \theta)$ and we use the notation $e^{\theta i}$ to mean the complex number $\cos\theta + i\sin \theta$.

This is called polar coordinates.

We can think of it as $z= re^{i\theta}$ where $r$ is the absolute value of $z$ and $e^{i\theta}$ is complex number that has the same angle or orientation or Arguement as $z$ but has an absolute value of $1$ and is on the unit circle.

Now here's where the magic happens:

$(a+bi)(c+di) = (ac-bd) + (bc+ad)i$ is relatively straightforward to calculate but $(a+bi)^k$ is a real pain.

But if $z = r(\cos \theta + i\sin \theta)$ and $w = s(\cos \phi +i\sin \phi)$ then

$zw = rx (\cos\theta + i \sin\theta)(\cos \phi +i\sin \phi)=$

$rs[(\cos\theta\cos \phi -\sin\theta\sin\phi) + (cos\phi\sin\theta + \cos\theta \sin \phi) i] =$

$rs[\cos(\theta + phi) + i\sin (\theta + \phi)]$.

That's magic as that makes multiplying complex numbers a matter of multiplying their absolute values and adding their angles.

So if $z = r(\cos\theta + i\sin \theta)$ then $z^k$ is a matter of multiplying by itself $k$ times so $z^k = r^k (\cos (k\theta)+ i\sin (k\theta))$.

Which we can write as $r^k e^{-k\theta}$.

End of crash course

.........

So here we go!

$z^3 - \omega = 0$ and $\omega = -\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 3} 2i$.

That's what $\omega$ is.

$\omega = r_{\omega} (\cos \theta_{\omega} +i \sin \theta_{omega})$

where $\rho = r_\omega = |z| =\sqrt{(-\frac 12)^2 + (\frac {\sqrt 3}2)^2} = 1$.  ANd $\theta_{\omega}$ is the unique angle where $\cos \theta = -\frac 12$ and $\sin \theta =\frac {\sqrt 3}2$.

That is $\theta_omega = \theta =\frac{2\pi}3$.

So $\omega = -\frac 12 + \frac {\sqrt 3} 2i=\cos \frac {2\pi}3 + i\sin \frac {2\pi}3 = e^{-\frac {2\pi}3}$.

So one of the cube roots will be found by the cube root of $1$ and dividing $\theta$ by $3$.

So $w_0 = \sqrt[3]1 \cdot e^{\frac {\frac {2\pi}3}3}$ or $e^{i\frac {\2\pi}9} = \cos \frac {2\pi}9 + i\sin \frac {2\pi}9$.

I'll leave it to you to figure the other two.

But note there a three angles and when you triple them they must all end up it the same angle.  The only way that happens is if you go around the circle.  That means the angles split a circle into three even parts.